# How to count a file in 2 folder and seperate the total of each folder using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have 2 folder. Inside those 2 folder has some files with 3 extension file (jpg, png, gif).
I want to count how many files in those 2 folders and specify the folder.

My expectation I can get this result

```
Folder1
.jpg = 12
.png = 2
.gif = 4

Folder2
.jpg = 6
.png = 4
.gif = 2
```

I tried this but I only count all the files in those folder, can not specify the folder.
Anyone can give idea, really appreciate for it. Thanks

```
$FindFolder = Get-ChildItem "D:\"
ForEach ($folder in $FindFolder)
{
    $folder
    Get-ChildItem -Name "D:\$folder" -Recurse -File  -Include *.jpg, *.png, *.gif | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object{$_.Count}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you something similar. This uses `Group-Object`, more details can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6). The `Select-Object` also uses [calculated expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) to get the parent folder of the files it finds.

All you need to do is adjust the `Get-ChildItem` to filter as you like!

```
$results = Get-ChildItem D:\ -Recurse -File | Select-Object Extension, `
    @{Name="Parent"; Expression={[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName)}}
$results | Group-Object Parent, Extension -NoElement | `
    Select-Object Count, @{Name="Extension"; Expression={($_.Name -split ',')[0]}}, `
    @{Name="Parent"; Expression={($_.Name -split ',')[1]}} | Sort-Object Count -Descending
```

Output:

```
Count Extension Parent
----- --------- ------
 2274  .pdf     D:\PDFBULK
 1509  .doc     D:\testFolder\SubFolder
  402  .msg     D:\testFolder\SubFolder
   97  .msg     D:\Marketing
```

Comment: I updated my question here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57602702/11076819 if you dont mind can help me to answer it. Thanks

Comment: @Drew - minor optimizations but you can get rid of the `$results` variable and you don't need the `Select-Object` before the `Group-By`. A shortened version could be something like `gci D:\ -File -Recurse | group directory, extension | select count, @{n='Extension';e={($_.name -split ',')[1]}}, @{n='Parent';e={($_.name -split ',')[0]}} | sort count -Descending`